# Storing user clicks from page to page within a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to coding. I have built a few sites using a web editor, but now am trying to use Cpanel. My question is how do I have a user click a button on one page, then get to another page of buttons to further refine the intial button. For example, buttons asking a model. The user selects the model, then is directed to a new page showing various colors of the model to select. Then chooses his color and is directed to even more refinement. I need to store each selection. What is this called? And how do I do it? I really have no idea where to begin on a Cpanel, and am thinking it's too advanced for me? Is there an easier way to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html

Comment: Dear friend, SO is not a code restaurant. Here, you have to ask a question with some code samples which are giving some error or are not working.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
 <html>
 <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
        function Redirect() {
           window.location="http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
        }
     //-->
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Click the following button, you will be redirected to home page.</p>

  <form>
     <input type="button" value="Redirect Me" onclick="Redirect();" />
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```